# Is 我去广州见朋友 or 我去广州看朋友 better for saying "I go to Guangzhou to see a friend"?

Tags: word-choice

In class, the teacher asked us to say:

> I go to Guangzhou to see a friend

in Chinese.  I thought we should say:

> 我去广州[见](http://dict.cn/%E8%A7%81)朋友
>   <sub>Wǒ qù Guǎngzhōu jiàn péngyǒu</sub>

but the (substitute) teacher proposed：

> 我去广州[看](http://dict.cn/%E7%9C%8B)朋友
>   <sub>Wǒ qù Guǎngzhōu kàn péngyǒu</sub>

I think 见 is more appropriate since it means "to see" in the sense of "to meet", whereas 看 means "to look at", e.g., 看花 (kànhuā) = to look at flowers.

I was corrected on this in the past: I went to an office and said 我想看[她的名字], and I was told that's weird to say, that it sounds like she's a celebrity, and I should say 我想见[她的名字].

However, in addition to the teacher's sentence, the top answer to [When to use 看 and 见？](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/8511/8099) says 见 is inappropriate (*you probably will not use 见 as a verb*), although it also says it is appropriate (*见 can be used as a verb when it means to see/meet someone*), so now I'm totally confused, and unsure which is best for this particular context.

**Question**: Is 我去广州见朋友 or 我去广州看朋友 better for saying "I go to Guangzhou to see a friend"?

Comment: 看 shows more emotions, like you care about him or her (similar to 看望), while 见 is neutral.

Comment: That answer confused itself, so don't be confused with that one. Lol, for sure, 见 can be used as a verb.

Comment: more possibilities; (search dictionaries): 看望朋友、会（会）朋友、见到朋友、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think 我去广州看朋友 is the suitable translation for "I go to Guangzhou to see a friend"? 我去广州看朋友 usually means you want to see your friend there to see how everything is going with him.

Well, 我去广州见朋友 sounds that you want to meet a friend in Guangzhou, usually for some purposes(like business, talking about something, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think English speaker will say "I go to some places to see a friend", even it is grammatically correct. Normally one will use : "I go to Guangzhou to visit/meet a friend".

Then you can learn how Chinese say the same thing interchangeably :

- 找朋友, 觅朋友， 觅友
- 探朋友，探望朋友
- 揾朋友， 睇朋友（Cantonese)
- 见朋友, 会见朋友， 会见友人， 看朋友

However, the later example of "looking/searching for somebody name", it is not correct to use [看/见] . The correct terms are

- 找名字
- 寻找名字
- 搜索名字

Comment: It's very common in English to use "see" like this, for example my coworker asked me this morning what I did last weekend and I answered "I went back home and saw my family".